# List of all option contracts

Tags: united-states, options, market-data

I am looking for a downloadable list of all option contracts for US equities, as opposed to resorting to scraping. A list of commodity options  would be a bonus.

I am looking for an official source that many other systems/sites use and hence will not change easily.

**My research so far:**

I have found resources [here](ftp://ftp.nasdaqtrader.com/symboldirectory/options.txt) and [here](http://www.nasdaqtrader.com/Micro.aspx?id=OptionsFeeds). However, these are   for NASDAQ only or what is available to trade via NASDAQ as part of interlinked ECN.

How about other exchanges like CBOE? Would they have option contracts listed that are not available in the nasdaqtrader.com  hosted options.txt file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For US markets, the complete list is available for free from the Options Clearing Corporation (OCC): [Directory of Listed Products](https://www.theocc.com/Market-Data/Market-Data-Reports/Series-and-Trading-Data/Directory-of-Listed-Products). Click on "Download Full Directory of Listed Products". The format of the file is specified in [DLP - HTTP Download Record Layout (PDF)](https://www.theocc.com/getmedia/a140e253-8f38-451f-ab0d-f90110443109/http-directory-record-layout.pdf).

Comment: Thanks Flux. In true SO fashion I have seen lately i saw someone instantly downvoted your answer with zero context that could help us learn and add value. Your link is spot on, i greatly appreciate your time in posting and cast an upvote to negate the mindless downvote.

Comment: @morleyc You're welcome. I must admit that I was the one who cast the fifth vote to close your question. I did that by mistake; I intended to abstain. Although your question appears to be off-topic, I believe it could be made on-topic with some edits (explicitly ask for official/regulatory sources of information).

Comment: Just general frustration of using SO on other sites for over a decade I have seen a trend more recently and fear of asking newb questions. I understand links will go out of date, however I don't see TheOCC going offline anytime soon given the many systems that will be wired to it (and their published webapi of sorts). I already have their data downloading into my reports thank you, and will try and make my questions more specific in future as you mention good point and well noted.